# WooCommerce - Getting total products count in the cart - not their quantity

Tags: woocommerce, cart

I have total cart quantity but I need count of products available in the cart. I donot want to show total quantity but want to show total products/orders in the cart.

Please help!

Comment: Please show how far you have done

Comment: hi Deshdeep, thanks for your reply. I have implemented the cart and everything. On the right top side, it appears eg. 10 items. There are 2 products having 5 quantity each in the cart. I want to show 2 orders instead of 10 items. Please suggest. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

i had same issue in client project @ [jivith.com](http://jivith.com)

But i resolved ...

Use in minicart / cart function replace total products count in the cart - not their quantity items

```
$_cartQty = count( WC()->cart->get_cart() );
**or** use sizeof (WC()->cart->get_cart());
```

i getting the total unique total products count in the cart instead of item of their quantity...

My demo code:

```
<span class="cart-items"><?php echo ($minicart_type == 'minicart-inline')
                        ? '<span class="mobile-hide">' . sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', $_cartQty, 'porto' ), $_cartQty ) . '</span><span class="mobile-show">' . $_cartQty . '</span>'
                        : (($_cartQty > 0) ? $_cartQty : '0'); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the total number of unique product is using `WC()->cart->cart_contents`. This contains an array of cart items. You can use array_unique() function to avoid repetition of the ids. So finally you can use array_count to get the count of unique products.

Comment: How get total number products on shop?

Answer (score 0):

I things Following code will help you. I had a issue i want to show total product counts not their quantity in the cart option.

If you change on `class-wc-cart.php` file just change php function `array_sum()` to `count()` it will work.

```
public function get_cart_contents_count() {   
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count', count( wp_list_pluck( $this->get_cart(), 'quantity' )) );
}
```